# Jenkins Global Tool Installation - Auto Install NodeJs Scripts

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, build-automation

I am trying to automate the global tools installation in Jenkins. My requirement is to install tools for **nodejs**, **golang** and **maven**. I was able to achieve the installation by running the following groovy script.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.tools.*
import jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.*
import jenkins.model.*

def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()
def desc = inst.getDescriptor("jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation")
def versions = [
  "nodejs-3.x": "3.7.0",
  "nodejs-4.x": "4.6.0",
]
def installations = []; 


for (v in versions) {
  def installer = new NodeJSInstaller(v.value, "", 100)
  def installerProps = new InstallSourceProperty([installer])
  def installation = new NodeJSInstallation(v.key, "", [installerProps])
  installations.push(installation)
}
desc.setInstallations(installations.toArray(new NodeJSInstallation[0]))
desc.save()
```

However, upon running the script overrides (basically deletes existing version of nodejs config) with currently provided versions in the script. I am looking for a solution append instead of overriding existing configuration.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Sample installation on Global Tool Configuration on Jenkins]

Comment: Have you tried out to get all existing installations `desc.getInstallations()`. I think you should get them and expand it by your versions - but be aware of duplicated.

Comment: I use the following for java, so you might use the same approach to install multiple versions. descriptor.setInstallations(installations.toArray(new JDK[installations.size()]))

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to import the existing elements as @terjekid said.

The code would should look something like this:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.tools.*
import jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.*
import jenkins.model.*

def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()
def desc = inst.getDescriptor("jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation")
def versions = [
  "nodejs-3.x": "3.7.0",
  "nodejs-4.x": "4.6.0",
]
**def installations = desc.getInstallations()  as List;** 


for (v in versions) {
  def installer = new NodeJSInstaller(v.value, "", 100)
  def installerProps = new InstallSourceProperty([installer])
  def installation = new NodeJSInstallation(v.key, "", [installerProps])
  **installations.add(installation)**
}
desc.setInstallations(**installations as jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation[]**)
desc.save()
```

i put bold tags around the relevent parts but that gets ignored i guess

successfully adapted from here: https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-client-plugin/issues/78