# Install Gradle and java with shell command in auto-install options in Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration" using groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

[image: Global Tool Config]

How to Install Gradle and java with shell command in auto-install options in Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration" using groovy ?
Please help me here

Comment: [Grade plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gradle/)

Comment: Manually I know how to do it, But im trying to write a groovy script for gradle auto install and java auto-install. Can anyone please give me any link for that, please

Comment: Use [JCasC](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2021/05/20/configure-plugins-with-jcasc/#content-top) to [manage the configuration](https://github.com/cloudbees-oss/cjd-jcasc-demo/blob/62672f3978568ce5f2619e91b35ddecded97e09f/jenkins.yaml#L403).

Comment: Or you could rip this [solution for Node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883158/598141), but JCasC is so straightforward.